# Click buttons in an website with javascript based on the their class and their child

Tags: javascript, html

How can I press all the buttons in a page given the html code below?

I want to get the button name, and if the child value matches `favorite_border` to automatically press the button.

```
<button type="button" class="UnstyledButtonreact__UnstyledButton-sc-ty1bh0-0 btgkrL"><i size="20" aria-label="Favorite" value="favorite_border" class="Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0 FavoriteIconreact__StyledIcon-sc-289aae-0 irmnIh fNbWaJ material-icons">favorite</i></button>
```

So far I've came up with the follwoing javascript code but the problem is that for other buttons are getting pressed too breaking the flow and redirecting me to a separate page.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('UnstyledButtonreact__UnstyledButton-sc-ty1bh0-0 btgkrL');

 for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  
     buttons[i].click();
```

Comment: `i` elements do not have a `size` or a `value` attribute.

Comment: _"So far I've came up with the follwoing javascript code"_ - I don't see any attempt in there to check, if the child has the value `favorite_border` ...?

Comment: Given the HTML you're showing, that's how you'd click them. If that clicks other buttons on the page, you'll need to show more HTML. Also, you should learn how [CSS selectors ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) work so that you can make more specific selectors to use with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more searches I figured the answer myself. The final code is:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('UnstyledButtonreact__UnstyledButton-sc-ty1bh0-0 btgkrL');


for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    var btn = buttons[i];
    var child = btn.firstChild;
    if (child.innerHTML == "favorite_border") {
        buttons[i].click();
}
```